# undefined reference to std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::recursive_directory_iterator functions in C++ after -lstdc++fs

Tags: c++, linux, g++, filesystems

I have a C++ code which includes `<experimental/filesystem>` header file. In `makefile` I do like this to compile the source code:

> g++ -Iinclude -c Filesystem.cpp -o Filesystem.o
> g++ -Iinclude -c main.cpp -o main.o
> g++ -o main.out Filesystem.o main.o

I run the makefile in terminal by `make LDLIBS=-lstdc++fs` and then `./main.out`

Compiler spits errors below and nags by:

```
/usr/bin/ld: Filesystem.cpp:(.text+0x106): undefined reference to std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::recursive_directory_iterator::~recursive_directory_iterator()
/usr/bin/ld: Filesystem.cpp:(.text+0x11a): undefined reference to std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::recursive_directory_iterator::operator*() const
/usr/bin/ld: Filesystem.cpp:(.text+0x232): undefined reference to std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::recursive_directory_iterator::operator++()
/usr/bin/ld: Filesystem.cpp:(.text+0x262): undefined reference to std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::recursive_directory_iterator::~recursive_directory_iterator()
/usr/bin/ld: Filesystem.cpp:(.text+0x271): undefined reference to std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::recursive_directory_iterator::~recursive_directory_iterator()
/usr/bin/ld: Filesystem.cpp:(.text+0x280): undefined reference to std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::recursive_directory_iterator::~recursive_directory_iterator()
/usr/bin/ld: Filesystem.cpp:(.text+0x31e): undefined reference to std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::recursive_directory_iterator::~recursive_directory_iterator()
/usr/bin/ld: Filesystem.cpp:(.text+0x32d): undefined reference to std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::recursive_directory_iterator::~recursive_directory_iterator()
```

Even though there is `__cxx11` in all errors, I checked my compiler version to see if I can use `recursive_directory_iterator` and this is the output:

```
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.1.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,d,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-bootstrap --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-cet=auto --enable-checking=release --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --enable-link-serialization=1 --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-multilib --enable-plugin --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-werror
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 13.1.1 20230429 (GCC)
```

Does it mean my compiler is below the version to support `recursive_directory_iterator`?

Thanks.

Comment: The compiler is rather *above* the version to be `experimental`. Try `#include<filesystem>` instead.

Comment: The content of `Makefile` is desired.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html

Comment: Please someone tells me what is wrong with all my question, marking up errors, makefile content, and tags that I got 2 negative points? @stackoverflow: this is not the proper way that any random person comes ghostly and hit the negative box and gets out. Either explain what is wrong or do nothing.

Comment: @BoP started to give the error that ```experimental``` is undefined when with only```#include<filesystem>```

Comment: @Iman - You use the very latest compiler version, but try to use code that was *experimental* 10 years ago. Just don't.

Comment: @BoP Thanks for your comment. I'll refactor the code right after getting the filesystem worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

adding `-lstdc++fs` in front of `g++ -Iinclude -c Filesystem.cpp -o Filesystem.o` and changing it to `g++ -Iinclude -c Filesystem.cpp -o Filesystem.o -lstdc++fs` solved the problem. Apparently running the makefile with `LDLIBS=-lstdc++fs` did not do the same thing.